# How add and remove items from a List using Flutter provider package?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am trying to add Items to a List `_bookMarkedItems`.

```
class Item with ChangeNotifer{
  String id;
  String title;
  bool isBookMarked;
  Item(this.id,this.title,this.isBookMarked);
  void toggleBookMark(){
    isBookMarked=!isBookMarked;
    notifyListneres();
  }
}
```

Items Class

```
class Items with ChangeNotifier{
 //recommendedBooks
  List<Item> _recommendedItems=[
  Item('1','Groccery'),
  Item('1','Groccery'),
 ];
  
  //Recommended
  List<Item> _discoverNew=[
  Item('1','Groccery'),
  Item('1','Groccery'),
 ];
 
 List<Item> _bookMarkedItems=[];
//getters
  List<Item> get recommendedItems{
  return [..._recommendedItems];
  }
  List<Item> get discoverNew{
  return [..._discoverNew];
  }
  
  List<Item> get bookMarkedItems{
  _recommendedItems.forEach((item){
    if(item.isBookMarked)
      _bookMarkedItems.add(item);
  });
      _discoverNew.forEach((item){
    if(item.isBookMarked)
      _bookMarkedItems.add(item);
  });
    return [..._bookMarkedItems];
  }
}
```

When I tap on any Item from `_discoverNew` or `_recommendedItems` in the homescreen.dart.
`//It builds the bookMarkedItems`

It ADDS them to the`_bookMarkedItems` .

But when I go back homescreen and tap on the item again.

`//It does not builds the bookMarkedItems`
and It does NOT update the and not REMOVE item from List`_bookMarkedItems`.
(Here is what I am not understanding).
I can add more items from the home page but cannot remove them.
In MyApp above myhomepage.dart`ChangeNotifierProvider(create:(_)=>Items(),..`
myitems.dart

````
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var savedItems= Provider.of<Items>(context).bookMarkedItems;
    print("**************Building savedItem List");
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIS8X.png
````

Comment: It is formatted properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the list of items null within bookMarkedItem function, like this : _bookMarkedItems = [];

Comment: That worked. I got it now.We cannot modify the original List which is instance member,we need to point it to a new List within the getter.

Answer (score 0):

try to change  isBookMarked = !isBookMarked

Comment: that was a typo on my end while writing this post.